# PDO script to get the amount of rows not working?

Tags: php, oop, pdo

I'm new to PDO PHP (just started today). I am attempting too write a login function, but it is returning false, even though i know the credentials are correct.

I think is is the attempt to get the amount of rows which is tripping the script up, can you help?

```
function check_login($email, $username, $password)
{
    $host = 'localhost';
    $port = 3306;
    $database = 'example';
    $username = 'root';
    $password = '';

    $dsn = "mysql:host=$host;port=$port;dbname=$database";
    $db = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
    $password = md5($password);

    $statement = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ? or username = ? and password = ?");
    $statement->execute(array($email, $username, $password));

    while ($result = $statement->fetchObject()) {
        $sql = "SELECT count(*) FROM users WHERE email = ? or username = ? and password = ?";
        $result1 = $db->prepare($sql);
        $result1->execute(array($email, $username, $password));
        $number_of_rows = $result1->fetchColumn();
        if ($number_of_rows == 1)
        {

            $_SESSION['login'] = true;
            $_SESSION['uid'] = $result->uid;
            return TRUE;
        }
        else
        {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. This:

   ```
   WHERE email = ? or username = ? and password = ?
   ```

   ... equals this:

   ```
   WHERE email = ? or (username = ? and password = ?)
   ```

   ... due to [operator precedence](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/operator-precedence.html). That means that if you validate with an e-mail address, you are not required to provide a valid password to log in.
2. Once you've found out whether the user exists, you make a second query to count the number of matching users. The database table should not be able to hold duplicate users in the first place! Columns `username` and `email` should be defined as unique indexes.
3. There's no point in using a `while` loop if it's going to `return` in the first iteration. It may work, but it's confusing.

This should be enough:

```
$statement = $db->prepare('SELECT uid FROM users WHERE (email = ? or username = ?) and password = ?');
$statement->execute(array($email, $username, $password));

if ($result = $statement->fetchObject()) {
    $_SESSION['login'] = true;
    $_SESSION['uid'] = $result->uid;
    return TRUE;
}else{
    return FALSE;
}
```

**Edit:** BTW, you should not be storing passwords in plain text. Countless sites have been hacked and their passwords stolen. Google for *salted passwords*.